# Which design pattern should be used instead of duplicate 'using(connection.opensession)' statement

Tags: c#, database, database-connection, ravendb, nosql

I am using RavenDB and it's require to open db session for each db action.
For example:
Create code:

```
 using (IDocumentSession session = _ravenContext.OpenSession()) 
  {                        
      session.Store(entity); 
      session.SaveChanges(); 
  }
```

GetById code:

```
using (IDocumentSession session = _ravenContext.OpenSession()) 
      {                        
           var entity= session.Load<T>(entityId);

      }
```

But I don't want to write the using() statement for each action (create, update, query and etc.)
Is there any design pattern or another way to write it more generic and without duplicate using() statement in code?

Thank in advance

Comment: `Execute(Action<IDocumentSession> executeAction)`

Comment: How about strategy pattern? You can inject the code to invoke with the open session into the method using a lambda.

Comment: How can I use lambda?
Please explain. be aware to the 2 example I gave. Thank

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to open the session once for handling a request. The idea of the session is that it keeps a lot of state for you to reduce your load.

In particular, opening a session per single db operation is probably a bad idea.

The common scenario is to open it when you start the request, and close & save changes when it is over.

An example of that can be seen here:

https://ayende.com/blog/4101/do-you-need-a-framework

Comment: Thank. According to your example the session will be open for each request.   
But not every request requires the ravensession.

Comment: Opening the session is very cheap, here is no extra cost

Comment: I have ASP MVC project and  Winform project. They are both use the raven project. The winform project is a job that run all the time. So where is the appropriate place to open the session in the winform project?